# Firebase upgrade plan after limits reached

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am reaching to the limits of the spark plan in firebase, and i was wondering if after that i cross the 100 connections and my project gets suspended, can i upgrade before that the month ends and keep using firebase?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your project does not get suspended when you've reached the maximum number of simultaneous connections.

When you have 100 users connected to your database that is in a free project, the database stops accepting new connections. Once one of the existing users disconnect, the database will accept the new connection again.

When you upgrade your project to a paid plan, the connection limit is immediately raised. There is no need to wait until the end of the month.

Comment: Take a look at the "What if I exceed my Spark or Flame plan limits?" in the pricing faq section. https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: Hmmm... that sounds unfamiliar to me. Let me ask around a bit where that came from (or if the behavior changed).

Comment: I filed a bug for that description, because it looks wrong (or at the very least one-sided). Expect it to be updated soon, but for now: the above is how the database works once you reach 100 simultaneous connections on the Spark plan.