# About when the maximum number of Firebase Realtime Database connections has been exceeded

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Realtime Database has an upper limit on the number of simultaneous connections, but what happens when the limit is exceeded?

How does Firebase Realtime Database behave especially when accessing from the Web using JavaScript?
Which of the following occurs: Canceled connection or waiting for a connection to connect?

self resolved

I tried and the connection was canceled.

code is nodejs.

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import log4js from 'log4js'

const logger = log4js.getLogger();

const config = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxxx",
  databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
};

let apps = [];
function connect(app_name) {
  const app = firebase.initializeApp(config, app_name);
  apps = [...apps, app];
  const database = app.database();
  database.ref(".info/connected").on("value", (snapshot) => {
    logger.info(`${app_name} status: ${snapshot.val()}`);
  })
}

for(let i = 0; i<100; i++) {
  const client_name = `client-${i}`;
  connect(client_name)
}

setTimeout(() => connect('client-100'), 4000);
setTimeout(() => connect('client-101'), 5000);
setTimeout(() => apps[0].database().goOffline(), 6000);
setTimeout(() => connect('client-102'), 7000);
```

tail output:

```
[2017-03-10 18:56:39.094] [INFO] [default] - client-2 status: true
[2017-03-10 18:56:39.432] [INFO] [default] - client-100 status: false
FIREBASE WARNING: Specified Firebase database has reached its Peak Connections limit.  If you are the Firebase owner, consider upgrading. (https://free-check.firebaseio.com)
[2017-03-10 18:56:40.431] [INFO] [default] - client-101 status: false
FIREBASE WARNING: Specified Firebase database has reached its Peak Connections limit.  If you are the Firebase owner, consider upgrading. (https://free-check.firebaseio.com)
[2017-03-10 18:56:41.435] [INFO] [default] - client-0 status: false
[2017-03-10 18:56:42.431] [INFO] [default] - client-102 status: false
[2017-03-10 18:56:43.013] [INFO] [default] - client-102 status: true
```

Comment: All Firebase SDKs handle this scenario the same way. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708449/firebase-upgrade-plan-after-limits-reached/41708526#41708526

Comment: I tried what was canceled