# Firebase Realtime Database Limit Exceed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know what will happen when the limit is exceeded for Firebase Realtime Database. The thing is I know the maximum number of connections I can have is 100 only. Now, suppose my android app has active 1,000 users and I implement Realtime Database. Then the first 100 users will get connect to the database. I want to know what will happen to the user number 101, how I know the connection is unsuccessful, is there any Exception that is thrown or some function isSuccessful(). How to handle that kind of thing in my app.

I have already seen: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708449/firebase-upgrade-plan-after-limits-reached/41708526#41708526) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708449/firebase-upgrade-plan-after-limits-reached)

I want to know how to tell the app that it is not connected and when any user disconnects, do I need to run init statement again and when?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708449/firebase-upgrade-plan-after-limits-reached/41708526#41708526

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase upgrade plan after limits reached](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708449/firebase-upgrade-plan-after-limits-reached)

Comment: I want to know how to tell the app that it is not connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/4RjyYIDqMVQ) from a Firebase developer

> There is no current way to detect this programmatically. An error
>   message will be asynchronously thrown in the developer console when
>   the 51st connection is made.

But this post is from 2014 so maybe that changed.

Comment: Nice effort. But the thing it is now acquired by Google and now things may have changed.